# ASP MVC: how to make url with passing array as parameter by RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing

I have a simple model.

```
class MyModel
{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<int> params{get;set;}
}
```

my action method is declared as:

```
public ViewResult Index(int id, IEnumerable<long> params)
```

and have a simple code on template with razor engine:

```
 @Html.BuildUrlFromExpression((ShareController c) => c.Index(Model.id, Model.params));
```

the thing `RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath` - this method returns an incorrect URL
as result i have url
fir example `@Url.Action("Index","Default",new {id=1, params = new long[]{11,33}});` get some value

```
/Default/Index/49?params=System.Int64%5B%5D;
```

it seems rather obvious fact that the construction of the address must correctly understand what type it is passed. I would want that the `BuildUrlFromExpression` gave the correct value.

```
/Default/Index/49?params=23&params=45
```

I have some work solution:

```
var rv = new RouteValueDictionary();
rv.Add("param[0]", 11);
rv.Add("param[1]", 33);
rv.Add("id", Model.CurrInFolderNum);
Url.Action("Index","default",rv)
```

but it works through the transmission of some number of parameters! I wish that would have been transferred to the array.
I think the answer somewhere on the surface.

Comment: I agree this is a deficiency in ASP.NET MVC (actually it's caused by a deficiency in System.Web.Routing.ParsedRoute), and I've opened an Issue on CodePlex for it: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/636

Comment: You are right! I looked at the source code and now I understand what to look the other way until the error is corrected. Is a pity that I wasted so much time.